# Why do we have to specify attributes of the <web-app> tag in the web.xml file?

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

Consider two web.xml files:
1.

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
 version="3.0">

  <display-name>app</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

2.

```
<web-app>

  <display-name>app</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The difference between them is that the `web-app` tag contains the attributes in the first one and the second one doesn't. The issue is if we apply the second `web.xml` we won't be able to use expressions like

```
${attrName}
```

in our `jsp`-pages. They won't be replaced with the corresponding values, added to a `model` in a `Controller` in the case of `Spring MVC`.

I thought, the only purpose we specify the `schemaLocation` attribute is to validate our `xml`-file (to get `XSD`-schema). How do the attributes actually work?

Answer (score 2):

The first web.xml specifies the version of the Servlet API that the webapp requires (3.0), whereas the second one doesn't.

In the second case, the servlet container will take that to mean it was written for an older version of the Servlet API, specifically from a version of the Servlet API that didn't use the version attribute or strictly defined namespaces. Those older versions were pre-JSP-2.0, and so don't support the JSP expression language. That means your expressions won't be substituted (you wouldn't want older app that used that expression syntax for some other reason to suddenly have them evaluated by the container in a way that the author didn't intend).

For a modern webapp-you should always specify the Servlet API version you need.

The `schemaVersion` version isn't relevant in itself, except to say that the modern versions of the Servlet API require them to be defined.